# Porting C++ Project to Android

Tags: c++, android

I have a big C++ application developed on windows,I need to port it to Android to run it as galaxy tab application.

I read many tutorials about NDK but it seems difficult to embed C++ files into Android.

Can I develop "DLL" using NDK? and invoke DLL from DLL?

any help would be  highly appreciated .

Answer (score 4):

Starting with 2.3, you can write android-applications completely in C++. Prior to 2.3, you had to create a shared object (the Linux equivalent of a DLL) using JNI, and call this from Java.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..can you please provide me any tutorial or link ?