# I have a small Vulkan project in VS C++ that runs on Windows. Can I make it run on Android in the same solution, supporting both Windows and Android?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, vulkan

I want my project to run on windows, and I want the ability to also run on Android. Basically one project that can run on two (or more) targets.

If not in VS, is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Porting C++ Project to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817131/porting-c-project-to-android)

Comment: Not looking to port the project to Android. Ideally I dont want to have to maintain two separate projects. I want to have my existing project support both Windows and Android platforms.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a project that can be built both for Windows and Android, I suggest you look into creating a CMake project.  CMake can be integrated both with VS and with Android Studio.

However, if you haven't done any Android NDK development, I suggest you start out with some Android-only examples first.

As an example, I work with a [fork](https://github.com/jherico/vulkan) of Sascha Willem's Vulkan examples.  In my fork I have a [cmake file](https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan/blob/cpp/CMakeLists.txt) that is used both to generate Visual Studio projects, and also referenced by the [Gradle build file](https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan/blob/cpp/android/build.gradle) for the Android build.

EDIT: removed incorrect statement about VS not supporting Android at all.

Comment: [Build amazing apps for Android with Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/android/)

Comment: There are configurations in VS that allow you to compile C++ code for Android (in addition to Xamarin allowing you to develop C# apps for Android). However, setting up a solution with both target configurations seems tricky to say the least. Perhaps CMake is the best way.